# Ansys Remote Solver with SLURM cluster

Tags: slurm

I am trying to connect Ansys running on CentOS 7 to use our HPC cluster which using SLURM as a scheduler.

I have looked into all the configuration file I could think of. I even wrote my custom `hps_commands_SLURM.xml` file I get the error

`Ansys.Rsm.Utilities.InvalidJobConfigurationFileException: : Expected element 'keyword' was not found in 'SLURM'`

I know, this question isn't very specific. I am at a loss here and will update the question as we go. I could use some direction with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a file within the RSM directory called `jobConfiguration.xml` which has entries in the form

```
<keyword name="SOMENAME">
    <jobCode name="name of GenericJobCode file to link" />
    <hpcCommands name="name of HPC COMMAND file to link">
    </hpcCommands>
</keyword>
```

In my case, I had to link my `hpc_commands_SLURM.xml` and also link a `GenericJobCode_SLURM.xml` in the appropriate keyword segments.